# Loading constant() value dynamically

Tags: angularjs, constants

Is it possible to declare an angular.constant("myLabels", {}), then load the value dynamically? In other words, the value of the constants is a JSON blob returned/set by a web service?

If so, what does this look like (e.g. pseudocode example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's the difference between `constant` and `value`. You may simply use [value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value):

```
app.value("myLabels", {});
```